# animate SVG in an if-else condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, jquery-animate

I am facing difficulties inserting the following **animate function inside an if-else statement to conditionally change the background color of an SVG**:

```
`<animate attributeName="fill" values = "#800;#f00;#800;#800‌​" dur="0.8s" repeatCount="indefin‌​ite" />`
```

If input is 1, then color is green, if 2, then color is blue & if 3 then color is red.

If the input is 3 (red), is it possible to let the color blink using the animate stated above or any other alternative?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/zs2q5nyg/6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <p id="Header" style="z-index:10000;position:absolute; top:30px; left:40%; margin:auto; color:Blue; font-size: 54px; font-family: BankGothic Md BT;font-weight: bold;"> Point Status </p> <br> <br><br> 
   <title>X</title>
   <style>
      div {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 1px;
      }
   </style>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

</head>
<body>

   <b>Enter # of Circles</b>
   <br>
   <input type="number" id="circles" min="1" step="1">   
   <form>
      <div id="Participentfieldwrap">
        <svg height="100" width="200">
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100000000" y2="10000" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5" />
            <svg height="100" width="100">
               <circle id="cir" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
               <animate id="ani" xlink:href="#cir" attributeName="fill" values = "#000;#000;#000;#000" dur="0.7s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </svg>
        </svg>
  <br>
        <b>Status</b>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="Color" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"  min="1" step="1">
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

   function myFunction(val) { 
    var val1=val.id.substring(val.id.indexOf("_")+1,val.id.length)
    var cir = document.getElementById("cir_"+val1);
    var into = document.getElementById("Color_"+val1);        
    var ani = document.getElementById("ani_"+val1);
    val=into.value;
                if(val*1 == 1){
                    cir.style.fill = "green";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#0f0;#0f0;#0f0;#0f0");
                }
                else if(val*1 == 2){
                    cir.style.fill = "blue";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#FFC200;#FFC200;#800;#FFC200");
                }
                else if(val*1 == 3){
                    cir.style.fill = "red";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#f00;#f00;#f00;#f00");
                }
                else if(val*1 == 4){
                    cir.style.fill = "blue";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#3333cc;#3333cc;#3333cc;#3333cc");
                }
                else{
                    cir.style.fill = "grey";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#99ccff;#99ccff;#99ccff;#99ccff");
                }
            }
         </script>
      </div>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input
  var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"), i, timer;

  function createCircles(val) { 
   // Removing previous circles
   while (form.firstChild) {
    form.removeChild(form.firstChild);
   }
   for(i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
    var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "Participentfieldwrap_" + i;
    clone.querySelector("input").id = "Color_" + i;
    clone.querySelector("circle").id = "cir_" + i;  
    clone.querySelector("animate").id = "ani_" + i;  
    clone.querySelector("animate").setAttribute("xlink:href", "#cir_" + i);
    form.appendChild(clone);
   }
  }

  ContestantNum.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
   if(timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
   }
   timer = setTimeout(function() {
    createCircles(ContestantNum.value);
   }, 0);
  });   
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A design pattern such as ' prototypal inheritance' would certainly make things easier

Comment: `if(val*1 == 1)` , why multiply by 1 ?

Comment: Usage of double `<b>` tags makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Service</title>
   <style>
      div {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 1px;
      }
   </style>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
</head>
<body>
   <b>Enter # of Circles</b>
   <br>
   <input type="number" id="circles" min="1" step="1">   
   <form>
      <div id="Participentfieldwrap">
        <svg height="100" width="200">
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100000000" y2="10000" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5" />
            <svg height="100" width="100">
               <circle id="cir" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
               <animate id="ani" xlink:href="#cir" attributeName="fill" values = "#fff;#000;#000;#000" dur="0.8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </svg>
        </svg>
  <br>
        <b>Color</b>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="Color" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"  min="1" step="1">
        <script type="text/javascript">       
   //Inputing integer 1, 2 or 3 which instantly applies color formatting (RGB) to circle in the same div         
            function myFunction(val) { 
    var val1=val.id.substring(val.id.indexOf("_")+1,val.id.length)
    var cir = document.getElementById("cir_"+val1);
    var into = document.getElementById("Color_"+val1);        
    var ani = document.getElementById("ani_"+val1);
    val=into.value;
                if(val*1 == 1){
                    cir.style.fill = "green";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#fff;#0f0;#0f0;#0f0");
                }
                else if(val*1 == 2){
                    cir.style.fill = "blue";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#fff;#00f;#00f;#00f");
                }
                else if(val*1 == 3){
                    cir.style.fill = "red";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#fff;#f00;#f00;#f00");
                }
                else{
                    cir.style.fill = "yellow";
                    ani.setAttribute("values", "#fff;#fefe00;#fefe00;#fefe00");
                }
            }
         </script>
      </div>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input
  var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"), i, timer;

  function createCircles(val) { 
   // Removing previous circles
   while (form.firstChild) {
    form.removeChild(form.firstChild);
   }
   for(i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
    var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "Participentfieldwrap_" + i;
    clone.querySelector("input").id = "Color_" + i;
    clone.querySelector("circle").id = "cir_" + i;  
    clone.querySelector("animate").id = "ani_" + i;  
    clone.querySelector("animate").setAttribute("xlink:href", "#cir_" + i);
    form.appendChild(clone);
   }
  }
   
  ContestantNum.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
   if(timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
   }
   timer = setTimeout(function() {
    createCircles(ContestantNum.value);
   }, 1);
  });   
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```